# Select the child[ren] of an element as one would select the descendant[s]

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

Say I have an `HTMLElement`:

```
var hoop = otherLibrary.getHoop()
```

I can select its descentant[s] that are `.stripey`:

```
var stripedOnes = hoop.querySelectorAll('.stripey')
```

This is like the CSS rule:

```
#hoop .stripey {
```

**However**, how do I do the same for child[ren], *without* using `jQuery`?

```
var stripedChildren = hoop.querySelectorAll('> .stripey')
```

Doesn't work, although in `jQuery`/`Sizzle` it does. What would be the JS equivalent of this CSS rule?

```
#hoop > .stripey {
```

Comment: If it works in Sizzle - maybe you can have a look how it's working there?

Comment: Well yes but I'm looking for the correct standard syntax to do this, not how `Sizzle` worked around it

Comment: Why not target it all inside the `querySelectorAll` ? `document.querySelectorAll("#hoop > .stripey");`

Comment: It could come from elsewhere, from a different module, etc

Answer (score 1):

Well, the most straightforward way would be to use the full selector inside `querySelectorAll()`

```
document.querySelectorAll("#hoop > .stripey");
```

**But, if answering your specific question...**

I believe the *fanciest* way to select an element's children based on a selector is:

1. turn the `.children` collection into an array
2. Filter each element testing it against a selector using `.matches()`

So:

```
var hoop = document.getElementById("hoop");
var stripedChildren = [].slice.call(hoop.children).filter(function(element) {
    return element.matches(".stripey");
});
```

Comment: But it'll be standardized as `matches()`

Answer (score -1):

**You can use following -**

```
document.querySelectorAll("#hoop > .stripey");
```